# Jquery post request from other url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a custom.js with  post request

```
function setPrayerTime(cityId) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "http://site.com/mymodule/namaz_mob/prayer.v2.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { cityId : cityId },
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
            $( ".namazcontainer" ).addClass( "times-loading" );
        }
    });
```

So, my PHP file is located at `site.com/mymodule/namaz_mob/prayer.v2.php`, but joomla always redirection to `site.com/prayer.v2.php`
if you're on the front page of the site i.e. `http://site.com` the ajax request will go to `http://site.com/prayer.v2.php` while on a page at `http://site.comblog/mypost01` it will map to `http://site.com/blog/prayer.v2.php`.
How to send ajax request of the address where located my php file `prayer.v2.php` within com_ajax

Comment: is `mymodule` a module in your modules folder or external folder placed in root directory?

Answer (score 1):

Likely there is some URL rewriting going over there.... What happens if you try the url like: `'/mymodule/namaz_mob/prayer.v2.php'` ?

However, I would recommend to use `com_ajax` the Joomla AJAX interface for making your ajax calls to your module's php functions. [**Read here for this**](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface).

Also do a search in JSE and you will find many similar topics that might help you. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=ajax+module

Comment: 'mymodule/namaz_mob/prayer.v2.php' same results, ajax post request redirection to site.com/prayer.v2.php

Comment: sorry try also with a slash in front of mymodule, like '/mymodule/namaz_mob/prayer.v2.php'

Comment: Same result even if you make a request from another domain

Comment: @Ummet - yes likely it is rewritten - as joomla has to pass this through index.php